при запуске отладки и сборки g++ возникает ошибка, при это изначально код запускался
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void scanf(string word){
    cout<<word<< endl;
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    scanf("hello");
    string words = "worrld";
    scanf(words);
    scanf("!!!");


return 0;
}  

код
сама ошибка в консоли
Выполнение задачи: C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /d /c g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow 
-Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -g3 -O0 -c c:\c.main\test.cpp -o .\build\Debug\test.o && g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -g3 -O0   .\build\Debug\test.o -o .\build\Debug\outDebug.exe 

C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file .\build\Debug\outDebug.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

 *  Процесс терминала "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe '/d', '/c', 'g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -g3 -O0 -c c:\c.main\test.cpp -o .\build\Debug\test.o && g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align - Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -g3 -O0   .\build\Debug\test.o -o .\build\Debug\outDebug.exe'" был завершен с кодом выхода 1. 
 *  Терминал будет повторно использоваться задачами. Чтобы закрыть его, нажмите любую клавишу. 


Один экземпляр программы работает во время сборки следующей версии, скорее всего он остановлен в отладчике, или повис, или ждёт ввода или что-то ещё. Windows на время работы программы блокирует исполнимый файл от записи и сборка не может записать новую версию.

Проще всего запустить TaskManager, отыскать там процесс с именем outDebug.exe и остановить его. После этого сборка сработает.

Это диспетчер задач.

<Ctrl+Shift+Esc>
